# How to stop threads when Toplevel() is closed

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I'm using tkinter with threading and for a while now, I've had a problem with my threads continuing even though all my windows are closed. The only way I can close the window is in the task manager.

This is my code:

```
def rootOnClose():
    save()
    main.deiconify()
    pygame.mixer.quit()
    root.destroy()

def advancetime():
    global datelabelstringvar
    global date
    global month
    global year
    global calendarthread
    calendarthread = threading.Timer(3.0, advancetime)
    calendarthread.setDaemon=(True)
    print(calendarthread.isDaemon())
    calendarthread.start()
    stockchange()
    if month == "09" or month == "04" or month == "06" or month == "11":
        date = int(date) + 1
        if date > 30:
            date = 1
            month = int(month) + 1
            if month > 12:
                month = 1
                year = int(year) + 1
        fixdate()
        fixmonth()
        datelabelstringvar.set(str(date) + "/" + str(month) + "/" + str(year))
        return
    if month == "01" or month == "03" or month == "05" or month == "07" or month == "08" or month == "10" or month == "12":
        date = int(date) + 1
        if date > 31:
            date = 1
            month = int(month) + 1
            if month > 12:
                month = 1
                year = int(year) + 1
        fixdate()
        fixmonth()
        datelabelstringvar.set(str(date) + "/" + str(month) + "/" + str(year))
        return
    if month == "02":
        date = int(date) + 1
        if date > 31:
            date = 1
            month = int(month) + 1
            if month > 12:
                month = 1
                year = int(year) + 1
        fixdate()
        fixmonth()
        datelabelstringvar.set(str(date) + "/" + str(month) + "/" + str(year))

def root():
    root = Toplevel()
    root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    main.withdraw()
    root.title("Fruit Clicker")
    root.geometry("400x350+300+100")
```

Ive tried adding `Daemons` but that doesn't seem to work. Ive also tried `calendarthread.join()` but that freezes my program. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You can cancel the timer with `calendarthread.cancel()` when you exit. Default `calendarthread = None` on startup so you can check whether there is a timer to be canceled. Also, if it can be set more than once, cancel the old one in the same way.

Comment: I dont know how to thank you. I've been trying to find a solution to this for months. THANKYOU!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@tdelaney answered this in the comments thank you so much

I needed to add `calendarthread.cancel()` in the `rootOnClose():` function